# Perl's Config::Simple doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the following to read parameters from a config file, but this doesn't seem to work. I am trying to read information from a file (I am open to any format as long as it is human readable). In the below example I am using an ini format.

```
 sub getPropInFile {
    my (    $pFile, #property file
            $pName  #property name
    ) = @_;
    #Debug messages
    print "DEBUG:: File Name  => $pFile\n";
    print "DEBUG:: Param Name => $pName\n";

    #Create a new Config object
    my $cfg = new Config::Simple();
    #Open file
    $cfg->read($pFile) or die $cfg->error();
    #Read the value of the param in the file
    my $val = $cfg->param($pName);

    #Debug messages
    print  "Param is :: $val\n";

    return $val;
}

Print getPropInFile ('app.ini', 'trend');
```

Param app.ini File:

```
[section 1]
trend=GoingUp
email=all
skip=no
active=true
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:: File Name  => app.ini
DEBUG:: Param Name => trend
Param is ::
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my machine right now, but a quick look at the docs gives me the impression you may need to use "section 1.trend" as your parameter name.